# Definite integral - Integration by parts

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $p,f,g,q$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$. How can  I show that
$$\int_a^b (pf'g'+qfg)dt=\int_a^b f(-(pg')'+qg)dt$$
Maybe by integrations by parts?

Comment: Are there any additional conditions, e.g. is $f(a) = f(b)$ or $p(a) = p(b)$ or $g'(a)=g'(b)$?

Comment: Maybe, indeed. And what happened when you tried to check this hunch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - almost:
$$\int_a^b f(-(pg')')\,dt=-[f(pg')]_a^b +\int_a^bf'(pg')\,dt$$
and now add $\displaystyle\int_a^b qfg\,dt$ to both sides.  Your claim is correct if and only if
$$[f(pg')]_a^b=0\ .$$